# How to add plugin fastlane-plugin-appicon in circleci?

Tags: ios, plugins, testflight, circleci, fastlane

I want to install the fastlane plugin fastlane-plugin-appicon, so I add add a command "- run: bundle exec fastlane add_plugin appicon" in the the circleci file, but there is something wrong, the circleci code and error log are as follows, thanks!

```
beta:
macos:
    xcode: "10.1.0"
    working_directory: /Users/distiller/project
environment:
  FL_OUTPUT_DIR: output
  FASTLANE_LANE: ios beta
shell: /bin/bash --login -o pipefail
steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
      name: pre-start simulator
      command: xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 8 (12.1)" || true
  - run:
      name: Set Ruby Version
      command:  echo "ruby-2.4" > ~/.ruby-version
  - run: brew update
  - run: brew cask install fastlane --no-quarantine
  - run: bundle update fastlane
  - run: bundle exec fastlane add_plugin appicon 
  - run: bundle install --path .bundle
  - run:
     name: Fastlane
     command: bundle exec fastlane $FASTLANE_LANE
  - store_artifacts:
      path: output
  - run:
      name: Transition Jira items for deployment
      command: .circleci/transition-jira-items.sh
```

[image]

[image]